# Time is lost in frame control by watir

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir-webdriver

I have a performance problem in a complex watir script. I isolate part of my code, and this is the result :

```
# Load browser and test page
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
@browser.goto ("http://myurl")

# Start to inspect time of script
puts "0 - Start             : " + Time.new.inspect

# Get active frame
frame = @browser.frame(:id => 'myFrame0123')
puts "1 - Frame is a variable   : " + Time.new.inspect

puts frame.exists?
puts "2 - Getting frame src         : " + Time.new.inspect

# play
frame.link(:class => "playButton").click # should be fast
puts "3 - Clicking link in frame    : " + Time.new.inspect

puts frame.exists?                  # should be instant
puts "4 - Getting frame src         : " + Time.new.inspect

# Closing
@browser.close
```

The code open a test page, detect a frame, and then click a link in the frame.

Here the result in firefox :

```
0 - Start                       : 2013-10-07 15:41:40 +0200
1 - Frame is a variable         : 2013-10-07 15:41:40 +0200
true
2 - Getting frame src           : 2013-10-07 15:41:40 +0200
3 - Clicking link in frame      : 2013-10-07 15:42:01 +0200
true
4 - Getting frame src           : 2013-10-07 15:42:54 +0200
```

The time is lost :

- between 2 and 3 : I don't understand how a click on a link in a frame take 20s ?
- between 3 and 4 : How a check of existence of a fram could take 50s ?

In chrome, the whole script take less than 10 seconds (As I wish)

Versions : ruby 1.9.3, watir-webdriver 0.6.4, firefox 21, 23, 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find why : in the frame I use, there is an image which doesn't exist. 
Firefox is slow and wait for the domain to respond, and this is why time is lost.